# Can we say that using "pass by reference" is always better than "pass by value"?

Tags: pass-by-reference

In C# or php or other languages, there are 2 ways to pass a value to a function, pass it by value and pass it by referece.

Pass parameter by value make the value copied in the function, so this need a extra memory space although the memory space will be reclaimed after running outside the function.

But passing parameter by reference no need to copy a value, it's save the memory. From this perspective, can we say that using "pass by reference" is always better than "pass by value"?

Comment: No, of course not. There are plenty of cases where you *want* to pass a copy of the variable instead of a reference. The memory usage of passing by reference versus passing by value falls under the category of a "micro-optimization" that's generally not important to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference and pass by value are semantically different and sometimes one is correct approach and sometimes the other one is. In many cases the task at hand already prescribes which approach is needed and in contexts where only one option is supported you often need to manually work around it (e.g., if you need a copy in Java you'll need to `clone()` the object).

In the context of generic functions the answer is rather the opposite way of your proposed preference: pass arguments of deduced type by value! The reason is that you can use something like `std::ref()` to obtain reference semantics but there is no way to get value semantics if the functions use reference semantics.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

There are tons of cases where you'd want to pass by value.

An example might be when you need both `const Type&` and `Type&&` overloads. Passing by value just handles both cases without having to duplicate any code:

```
void function(Object o) { do_something_with(std::move(o)); }
```

As opposed to:

```
void function(Object&& o) { do_something_with(std::move(o)); }
void function(const Object& o) { do_something_with(Object(o)); }
```

Of course there is much more to the subject, but since you're only asking for "*is it **always** better?*" I feel a single disproving example is enough. ;)

**Edit**: the question was originally tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) hence my very specific answer.

---

Another, more language-agnostic example would be when you need to make a copy of your parameter because you don't want to modify the original object:

```
void function(int& val) { int v2 = val; modify(v2); use(v2); }
// vs
void function(int val) { modify(val); use(val); }
```

You get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference requires copying a reference to the object. If that reference is comparable in cost to the object itself, then the benefit is illusory. Also, sometimes you *need* a copy of the object, and passing by value provides you one.

Also, there's a key error in the reasoning in the question. If passing by value, and there is no need to copy the value, nothing requires that the value actually be copied. Most languages have an "as-if" rule that states that the program only has to act as if the compiler did what you ask for. So if the copy can be avoided, the compiler is free to avoid it. If the copy can't be avoided, then you needed the copy.